# Update a web parts zone using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-part, properties, web-part-zone

Is it possible for me to update a web parts zone property using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Hmm.. I see in your name you are stil using IE5 . Its going to be hard then.

Comment: I truly hope that was a joke.

Comment: Not if you are actually on IE5

Comment: I am not using IE5.

Comment: You have to look for JSOM code then, but I have never seen it. Try PnP and doing it with CSOM thru PowerShell. If PnP can't do then you for sure can not do it with Client Side JSOM code